# Why the adjustable spring tension on the cage of Shimano rear derailleurs?

Tags: derailleur-rear

Why do some Shimano rear derailleurs have an adjustable cage spring tension and what is affected by increasing it (default is low tension)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a way of mitigating chain slap and chain retention issues, primarily for more aggressive riding styles. The tradeoff is drivetrain efficiency and shifting smoothness. It's a feature that's basically been supplanted by rear derailer clutches.

Comment: Lower tension, standard position: quicker shifting but risk of unwanted chain behaviour. Higher tension; if the standard setting doesn't work mainly because of bumpy riding conditions but requiring a more precise derailleur adjustment.to ensure correct gear changes.